# Return First and Last Parameter passed in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, arguments

Want to write function that return first and last parameter passed.

```
const firstLastArg = () =>{
//  return first and last argument passed as 1 and 5
}

console.log(firstLastArg(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Is any way to achieve ?

Comment: You can only return a single value from a function. What do you actually want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use rest parameters syntax `...` this operator will wrap your params into an array, and from that array you can easily get the first and last value.

```js
const firstLastArg = (...args) => [args[0], args[args.length - 1]];

console.log(firstLastArg(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Comment: And for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: There is no "spread operator". The syntax you're using is a *rest parameter*.